# How to use platformBrowser instead of platformBrowserDynamic with angular-cli app in maint.ts to bootstrap app in aot mode?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am building the app with angular cli with aot=true and --prod so the app gets compiled with aot and bundle sizes are smaller, but how do I bootstrap the app in aot mode so that the bootstrap is faster like explained in [this article](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/12/16/bootstrapping-angular-2-with-ahead-of-time-template-compilation/)?

Current code:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (!environment.local) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Code proposed by article:

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
//** where is the following file generated by angular-cli? **
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app/app.module.ngfactory';

if (!environment.local) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Where do I find app.module.ngfactory? Is this even needed? Or using platformBrowserDynamic with aot with angular cli still somehow results in aot bootstrap instead of jit bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

This is a super old question but I stumbled on it while trying to solve something similar.

> When the dynamic platform is used, this factory is created each time you load your application; however, now we are creating it before our application even runs. The `AppModuleNgFactory` is not going to exist until you build your application with `ngc`....

> It is likely that ngc was installed with your angular application, so in order to run ngc, you’ll just have to run `./path/to/node_modules/.bin/ngc -p ./path/to/src` in your project directory. If it’s not installed, you can install it with `npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler`.

Running `./node_modules/bin/ngc` out of the root (where your project's `tsconfig.ts` exists) works to generate this file.